# SQL Server query to check availability of book in library

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to check whether entered book no is available or not. I have used `BOOK` table where all the books are added. There is another table named `BORROWED` where `Issuedate`,`Returndate` are listed. Here is the query

```
select * 
from BORROWED, BOOK 
where BookCode = ? 
  and BORROWED.BookCode = BOOK.BookCode 
  and BORROWED.Returned is null
```

But showing this error :

> Ambiguous column name 'BookCode'

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

You have a column called `BookCode` in both tables. You need to name the table. Otherwise the DB engines does not know which one you mean.

```
SELECT *
FROM BORROWED
JOIN BOOK ON BORROWED.BookCode = BOOK.BookCode
WHERE BORROWED.BookCode = ?
  AND BORROWED.Returned IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases and join

```
SELECT `b`.*
  FROM `BORROWED` `b`
  INNER JOIN `BOOK` AS `c` ON `c`.`BookCode` = `b`.`BookCode`
  WHERE `b.`BookCode` = ?
    AND `b`.`Returned` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message is generated due to the fact that both your tables have that same column name. To prevent these type of errors get used to using *aliases* in  your queries:

```
   SELECT *
    FROM BORROWED AS br 
        JOIN BOOK AS b 
            ON b.BookCode = br.BookCode
            WHERE 
                br.BookCode = ?
            AND br.Returned IS NULL
```